# join the values of two strings in a single loop

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex-18.2

I have below Two Strings

`Src Id = 1:2:3:4`

`Src Qty = 2:4:7:9`

So I want to Insert into a Table like

```
Insert into tbl (Src_id,qty) values (1,2);
Insert into tbl (Src_id,qty) values (2,4);
Insert into tbl (Src_id,qty) values (3,7);
```

and so on for all

So How i can use a loop by using `APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE` or something else to align the Src id and Qty to insert them as single row in a table

Answer (score 0):

I have done the Solution as below

```
DECLARE
   l_src_arr2   APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
   l_qty_arr2   APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;

BEGIN
   l_src_arr2 := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE ('1:2:3:4');
   l_qty_arr2 := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE ('2:4:7:9');

   FOR i IN 1 .. l_src_arr2.COUNT LOOP

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Src = ' || l_src_arr2 (i) || ' qty = ' || l_qty_arr2 (i));

   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop (i.e. PL/SQL); everything can be done in SQL. Here's how:

```
SQL> with test (src_id, src_qty) as
  2    (select '1:2:3:4', '2:4:7:9' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(src_id, '[^:]+', 1, level) ||','||
  4         regexp_substr(src_qty, '[^:]+', 1, level) result
  5  from test
  6  connect by level <= regexp_count(src_id, ':') + 1;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------
1,2
2,4
3,7
4,9

SQL>
```

Comment: I need this in loop , can u check my answer is this enough

Comment: If it does what you want it to do, then it *is enough*.